# how to use data setting in react componentWillMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I want to get initial Data when component is rendering before.
So, I try to state update action in componentWillMount.
Although state change, when I confirm console result at componentDidMount result is blank.

imageUpload.js

```
export const IMAGE_UPLOAD = 'IMAGE_UPLOAD';
export function imageUpload(photo) {
  return {
    type: IMAGE_UPLOAD,
    photo
  }
}
```

Reducers.js

```
import { IMAGE_UPLOAD } from './actions/imageUpload';

export default function imageUpload(state = {photo: ''}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case IMAGE_UPLOAD:
      return {
        ...state,
        photo: action.photo
      }
    default:
      return state
   }
}
```

App.js

```
import photo from './data/photo.json' // photo type: json
import imageUpload from './actions/imageUpload'

componentWillMount() {
  Storage.prototype.setObject = (key, value) => {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
  }
  Storage.prototype.getObject = (key) => {
    return this.getItem(key) && JSON.parse(this.getItem(key))
  }
  const photoData = localStorage.getObject('photos');
  if(photoData) // data in localStorage
    imageUpload(photoData) // state setting localStorage data
  else // data not in localStorage
    imageUpload(photo) // state setting photo json data
}

componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.props.photo); // result: blank ( I want result: any value)
}

class App extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  photo: state.imageUpload.photos
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>({
  imageUpload: bindActionCreators(imageUpload, dispatch)
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

What sholud I do?
Thank you.

Comment: is there a typing mistake in mapStateToProps ...instead of  `photo: state.imageUpload.photos` it should be `photo: state.imageUpload.photo`

Comment: If the componentDidMount function is part of the connected component (it is unclear in your code), it does not have a photo object in its props. You need to look at the child component and look at its prop.

Answer (score 0):

The Redux state update is asynchronous, which means that it'll take *some* time for the Redux state to update. The reason why you're not seeing any data in the `componentDidMount` is because the redux async action is still not complete by the time that method is called.

Try looking for the data in `componentWillRecieveProps`. This method will get called with the data when the asynchronous action completes.

So:

```
componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps.photo);
}
```

Comment: Regular redux actions and their dispatch are synchronous by default. If you want to utilize async dispatches, you have to use 3rd party techniques like [Thunks](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or [Epics](https://github.com/BerkeleyTrue/redux-epic).